# Why do the indentations in my model become hollow?

Tags: modifiers, faces

I'm trying to add a face in the centre of my model, but the indentations I created disappear whenever I do so.

[image: This is the model without the face at the top]

[image: This is the model after the I added the face]

Comment: Hello, could you please share your object? https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: Sure thing, I've sent it now

Comment: you'll need to share the URL it will generate

Comment: I think I fixed it, the solution was as simple as turning the solver in the Boolean Modifier from Exact to Fast. I'll test it in this condition and see how it goes!